# Powershell - List value of boxes checked

Tags: powershell

I have a Powershell scripts that creates 12 unique check boxes.  Later in the script, it creates an email and enter information.  I am trying to get the email to include the value of the boxes that are checked, and not the others.  The variable name for each box is $CB1 up through $CB12.

```
Team,

Per ticket $SCTicket, $User is requesting access to GetPaid.

Details from RITM ticket $RITMTicket are below:

Access Type: $AccessType
Roll: $Roll
Responsibilities: 


Thank You
```

Doing something such as $CB1,$CB2,$CB3, ect. does not look right, as it leaves a bunch of random commas.  Putting each checkbox value on it's own line can work, but then there are potentially several blank lines for no reason.

If the user checks off, say, boxes 4, 7, and 10, how can I get just those values written??

Full code is below:

```
if ($startupvariables) { try {Remove-Variable -Name startupvariables  -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } catch { } }
New-Variable -force -name startupVariables -value ( Get-Variable | ForEach-Object { $_.Name } )

Write-Output "Don't close this window!"
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::OKCancel
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning
$MessageTitle = "GetPaid - Access Request"
$MessageBody = "This script sends a GetPaid access request setup to xxxxxxxx and xxxxxx.`n`nTo use it, enter the below information:`n`n`n`tTicket Number`n`n`tUser's Email Address`n`n`tAccess Requested`n`n`nIf this is the script you want to use, click OK.`nIf not, click Cancel."
$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)

if ($Result -eq "Cancel")
{
Exit-PSSession
}
else

{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$Separator = ".", "@"

$SCTicket = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the SCTask ticket number" , "Ticket Number")

$RITMTicket = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the RITM ticket number" , "Ticket Number")

$UserID = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter the user's email address" , "User Email Address")
$User = $UserID.split($Separator)
$Firstname = $User[0].substring(0,1).toupper()+$User[0].substring(1).tolower()
$Lastname = $User[1].substring(0,1).toupper()+$User[1].substring(1).tolower()
$User = $Firstname, $Lastname

function Access_Type{
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 225
$Form.height = 215
$Form.Text = ”Select Type of Access"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",11)
$Form.Font = $Font

$MyGroupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$MyGroupBox.Location = '5,5'
$MyGroupBox.size = '190,125'

$RadioButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton1.Location = '20,20'
$RadioButton1.size = '120,30'
$RadioButton1.Checked = $false 
$RadioButton1.Text = "Grant"
$RB1 = "Grant"
$RadioButton2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton2.Location = '20,50'
$RadioButton2.size = '120,30'
$RadioButton2.Checked = $false
$RadioButton2.Text = "Change"
$RB2 = "Change"
$RadioButton3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton3.Location = '20,80'
$RadioButton3.size = '120,30'
$RadioButton3.Checked = $false
$RadioButton3.Text = "Revoke"
$RB3 = "Revoke"

$OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = '5,135'
$OKButton.Size = '90,35' 
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult=[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$CancelButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = '105,135'
$CancelButton.Size = '90,35'
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$CancelButton.DialogResult=[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($MyGroupBox,$OKButton,$CancelButton))
$MyGroupBox.Controls.AddRange(@($Radiobutton1,$RadioButton2,$RadioButton3))
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})    
$dialogResult = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($DialogResult -eq "OK")
{
if ($RadioButton1.Checked){$global:AccessType = $RB1}
elseif ($RadioButton2.Checked){$global:AccessType = $RB2}
elseif ($RadioButton3.Checked){$global:AccessType = $RB3}
}
elseif ($DialogResult -eq "Cancel")
{
break
}
}
Access_Type

function Access_Roll{
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 225
$Form.height = 180
$Form.Text = ”Select Type of Access"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",11)
$Form.Font = $Font

$MyGroupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$MyGroupBox.Location = '5,5'
$MyGroupBox.size = '190,90'

$RadioButton1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton1.Location = '20,20'
$RadioButton1.size = '130,30'
$RadioButton1.Checked = $false 
$RadioButton1.Text = "User"
$RB11 = "User"
$RadioButton2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$RadioButton2.Location = '20,50'
$RadioButton2.size = '130,30'
$RadioButton2.Checked = $false
$RadioButton2.Text = "Administrator"
$RB22 = "Administrator"

$OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = '5,100'
$OKButton.Size = '90,35' 
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult=[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$CancelButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = '105,100'
$CancelButton.Size = '90,35'
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$CancelButton.DialogResult=[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($MyGroupBox,$OKButton,$CancelButton))
$MyGroupBox.Controls.AddRange(@($Radiobutton1,$RadioButton2))
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})    
$dialogResult = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($DialogResult -eq "OK")
{
if ($RadioButton1.Checked){$global:Roll = $RB11}
elseif ($RadioButton2.Checked){$global:Roll = $RB22}
}
elseif ($DialogResult -eq "Cancel")
{
break
}
}
Access_Roll

function Access_Responsibilities{
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 265
$Form.height = 510
$Form.Text = ”Select Type of Access"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Verdana",11)
$Form.Font = $Font

$MyGroupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$MyGroupBox.Location = '5,5'
$MyGroupBox.size = '230,420'

$Checkbox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox1.Location = '20,20'
$Checkbox1.size = '200,25'
$Checkbox1.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox1.Text = "Collections"
$CB1 = "Collections"

$Checkbox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox2.Location = '20,45'
$Checkbox2.size = '200,25'
$Checkbox2.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox2.Text = "Credit Management"
$CB2 = "Credit Management"

$Checkbox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox3.Location = '20,70'
$Checkbox3.size = '200,25'
$Checkbox3.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox3.Text = "Cash Application"
$CB3 = "Cash Application"

$Checkbox4 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox4.Location = '20,95'
$Checkbox4.size = '200,25'
$Checkbox4.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox4.Text = "Sales and Service User"
$CB4 = "Sales and Service User"

$Checkbox5 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox5.Location = '20,115'
$Checkbox5.size = '200,50'
$Checkbox5.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox5.Text = "Controller (specify plant below)"
$CB5 = "Controller (specify plant below)"

$Checkbox6 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox6.Location = '20,160'
$Checkbox6.size = '200,50'
$Checkbox6.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox6.Text = "Plant (specify plant below)"
$CB6 = "Plant (specify plant below)"

$Checkbox7 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox7.Location = '20,205'
$Checkbox7.size = '200,25'
$Checkbox7.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox7.Text = "Sales"
$CB7 = "Sales"

$Checkbox8 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox8.Location = '20,230'
$Checkbox8.size = '200,25'
$Checkbox8.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox8.Text = "Pricing"
$CB8 = "Pricing"

$Checkbox9 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox9.Location = '20,255'
$Checkbox9.size = '200,25'
$Checkbox9.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox9.Text = "Warranty"
$CB9 = "Warranty"

$Checkbox10 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox10.Location = '20,280'
$Checkbox10.size = '200,25'
$Checkbox10.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox10.Text = "GL Accountant"
$CB10 = "GL Accountant"

$Checkbox11 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox11.Location = '20,300'
$Checkbox11.size = '200,50'
$Checkbox11.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox11.Text = "Mexico Billing (specific plant below)"
$CB11 = "Mexico Billing (specific plant below)"

$Checkbox12 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Checkbox
$Checkbox12.Location = '20,340'
$Checkbox12.size = '200,75'
$Checkbox12.Checked = $false 
$Checkbox12.Text = "Non Problem Owner (To be used for Inquiry Only)"
$CB12 = "Non Problem Owner (To be used for Inquiry Only)"

$OKButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = '10,430'
$OKButton.Size = '90,35' 
$OKButton.Text = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult=[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$CancelButton = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = '110,430'
$CancelButton.Size = '90,35'
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$CancelButton.DialogResult=[System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$form.Controls.AddRange(@($MyGroupBox,$OKButton,$CancelButton))
$MyGroupBox.Controls.AddRange(@($Checkbox1,$Checkbox2,$Checkbox3,$Checkbox4,$Checkbox5,$Checkbox6,$Checkbox7,$Checkbox8,$Checkbox9,$Checkbox10,$Checkbox11,$Checkbox12))
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})    
$dialogResult = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($DialogResult -eq "OK")
{
if ($Checkbox1.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB1}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB2}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB3}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB4}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB5}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB6}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB7}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB8}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB9}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB10}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB11}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB12}
}
elseif ($DialogResult -eq "Cancel")
{
break
}
}
Access_Responsibilities

function Read-MultiLineInputBoxDialog([string]$Message, [string]$WindowTitle, [string]$DefaultText)
{
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$label.AutoSize = $true
$label.Text = $Message

$textBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$textBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$textBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(575,200)
$textBox.AcceptsReturn = $true
$textBox.AcceptsTab = $false
$textBox.Multiline = $true
$textBox.ScrollBars = 'Both'
$textBox.Text = $DefaultText

$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(415,250)
$okButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$okButton.Text = "OK"
$okButton.Add_Click({ $form.Tag = $textBox.Text; $form.Close() })

$cancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$cancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(510,250)
$cancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,25)
$cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$cancelButton.Add_Click({ $form.Tag = $null; $form.Close() })

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = $WindowTitle
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(610,320)
$form.FormBorderStyle = 'FixedSingle'
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.AutoSizeMode = 'GrowAndShrink'
$form.Topmost = $True
$form.AcceptButton = $okButton
$form.CancelButton = $cancelButton
$form.ShowInTaskbar = $true

$form.Controls.Add($label)
$form.Controls.Add($textBox)
$form.Controls.Add($okButton)
$form.Controls.Add($cancelButton)

$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
$form.ShowDialog() > $null

return $form.Tag
}
$global:Comments = Read-MultiLineInputBoxDialog -Message "Enter any comments from the ticket" -WindowTitle  "Comments"

$Username = [System.Environment]::UserName
$subject = "Ticket $SCTicket - $User's GetPaid Access Request"
$body = "

Team,


Per ticket $SCTicket, $User is requesting access to GetPaid.

Details from RITM ticket $RITMTicket are below:


Access Type: $AccessType

Roll: $Roll

Responsibilities: 

Comments: $Comments



Thank You, 
"

$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::YesNo
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Warning
$MessageTitle = "GetPaid - Access Request"
$MessageBody = "The information you have entered is show below:`n`n`nTicket Number: $Ticket`n`nUser's Email Address: $UserID`n`nAccess Type: $AccessType`n`nRoll: $Roll`n`nResponsibilities: `n`nComments: $Comments`n`n`nIf you would like to send the email, click Yes.`nOtherwise, click No."
$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)
if ($Result -eq "No")
{
Exit-PSSession
}
else

{
Send-MailMessage -To "<$Username@xxx.com>" -bcc "<$Username@xxx.com>" -from "<itservicedesk@xxx.com>" -Subject $subject -SmtpServer "mailrelay.xxx.com" -body $body
}
}

Function Clean-Memory {
Get-Variable |
 Where-Object { $startupVariables -notcontains $_.Name } |
 ForEach-Object {
  try { Remove-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Force -Scope "global" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue}
  catch { }
 }
}
```

Comment: It will be tough to help you without seeing what you are actually doing problematically. [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay, to make it less problematic then...Imagine you have a list, A-L, each with it's own checkbox.  Each box is assigned a variable, $CBA through $CBL.  You select the boxes next to D, G, and J.  You now want to include those in an email you are sending which is created by a script (all of this already works; you can change it to return in the console if you want).  You only want to return $CBD, $CBG, and $CBJ.  How do you do it?

Comment: Please include your code as a [mcve]. Without showing your code your question is as useful as an answer that doesn't tell you the function to use but just describes what it does.

Comment: Also if you have further information to make your question better please edit your question to add the information.

Comment: Understood.  Full code has been added to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: According to your code `$CB1` through `$CB12` are not the actual checkboxes, `$Checkbox1` through `$Checkbox12` are.  So you would use `$Checkbox1.Checked` to see if the checkbox is checked or not

Comment: Yes, this is true.  I was following the same format I used for the radio buttons.  However, even if I switch it to match what you have provided, I still need to be able to include that (and any other boxes checked) in my output without formatting issues.
For instance, the example I gave should list D, G, J, and not list (space),(space),(sp)D,(sp),(sp),G, ect....
This is where I am confused on how to proceed.

Comment: Great question and a good example of responding to feedback and providing more info in a timely manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from a preliminary look through the code and the question that you are asking, this is what I have come up with.

Basically, if the checkbox is checked, it appends the $CB(1-12) string to the `$global:AccessResponsibilities` and then in your email just reference `$global:AccessResponsibilities` and it should have all the strings of the checkboxes that were checked

```
if ($Checkbox1.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB1 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB2 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox3.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB3 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox4.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB4 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox5.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB5 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox6.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB6 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox7.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB7 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox8.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB8 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox9.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB9 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox10.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB10 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox11.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB11 + "`r`n"}
if ($Checkbox12.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities += $CB12 + "`r`n"}
```

Comment: Okay, so I see where this code is to be inserted.  Then, in the email itself, the line would be "Responsibilities: $AccessResponsibilities", correct?

Comment: @sbagnato `$global:AccessResponsibilities` yes

Answer (score 3):

Here's a procedural way to retrieve the matching values.

First, we retrieve all variables with `$Checkbox` in the name, then grab only ones with a `CheckState` value.  Then, for each, we substring out the number and append that to the string `CB` to retrieve the value of the corresponding `$CB#` variable.

Then we store that in an array list and join with a comma at the end, for the output you see below.

```
$properties = New-object System.Collections.ArrayList
$CheckedBoxes = Get-Variable checkbox* | Where-object {$_.Value.CheckState -eq 'Checked'} 
ForEach ($Checked in $CheckedBoxes){

   $CBNumber = $CheckBox.Name.Split('Checkbox')[-1]
   $Properties.Add((Get-variable "CB$CBNumber").Value) | out-null
}

$Properties -join ','

>GL Accountant, Pricing, Credit Management
```

All of this code should be used where you have this code today:

```
if ($Checkbox1.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB1}
#Insert new code here <---------------
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB2}
elseif ($Checkbox2.Checked){$global:AccessResponsibilities = $CB3}
```

Answer (score 2):

heres a small loop that should work for HeedfulCrayon's answer.

```
foreach ($i in 1..12)
{
    if ((Get-Variable -Name Checkbox$i).Value.Checked)
    {
        $Global:AccessResponsibilities += ((Get-Variable -Name CB$i).Value + "`r`n")
    }
}
```